# Multiple versions of themed question

Tags: discussion

Am I allowed to post another question with the same theme as my previous question, but with a different approach?

If so, should I title these questions 'version 1' and 'version 2' or be more specific in the title?

---

Update:

Version 1: [This is the first question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/33221/domino-function)

Version 2: The next question (which may be classed as duplicate) would be identical apart from the function would receive different parameters (an integer and an array, as opposed to three integers)

Comment: I think you should be more specific in this question here, because I don't really know what you mean by "theme" and "approach". Could you point us to the first question and tell us what you want the second one to be like?

Comment: @m.buettner Please see my edit

Comment: Yes, that does seem to be too close to not be a duplicate. It doesn't really change the actual algorithm used, merely the input parsing (which could be fine if input parsing was the most interesting part of the challenge to begin with, but I'm not sure that's the case).

Comment: @m.buettner The idea with using an array is so that you can knock a domino left or right an indefinite amount of times, moving various dominos in the process. Much better than a one shot deal that the V1 function gives.

Comment: I see. That might make a difference, but still the core algorithm would barely need to change (just check for where to stop) and then you'd wrap it in the loop. I thought I'd let you know, though, that I came up with a different challenge inspired by yours: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1861/8478 ... feel free to help me polish it for main.